# Сравнение программно заданной строки со считанной с клавиатуры

Tags: c, строки, libc

Имеется участок кода:

```
cin.getline(b, 200, '\n');
send(s, b, sizeof(b), 0);
if (strcmp(b, "sms") && (b[3] =='\0')) {
    recv(s, b, sizeof(b), 0);
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

Задача - если введенная строка это "sms", то получить определенную строку с сервера и вывести её на экран. Однако почему-то в тело условия программа не заходит, непонятно по какой причине. По отладке смотрел, первые 3 символа введенной с клавиатуры строки это `'s'` `'m'` `'s'`, а четвертый `'\0'`. Поэтому не понимаю в чем проблема.

Comment: Потому что если строки равны, то strcmp возвращает НОЛЬ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
if (strcmp(b, "sms") && (b[3] =='\0')) {
```

на

```
if (strcmp(b, "sms") == 0) {
```